# Does my wallet.dat file contain all wallets?

Tags: bitcoin-core, wallet, wallet-recovery, wallet.dat

I have backed up my wallet.dat file, but now I find myself wondering if bitcoin core stores all newly generated wallets in the same wallet.dat file. Of course this is after having accidentally deleted some files I shouldn’t have. Can I safely restart my computer and download bitcoin core again, and load the old wallet.dat file or should I have seperate wallet.dat files for every newly generated wallet?

Comment: Do you actually mean separate wallets, or just multiple addresses? A wallet.dat file contains one wallet, but all its addresses.

Comment: That is exactly what I am not so sure about - I never modified/replaced the wallet.dat file, but I clicked create new wallet in bitcoin core - is that wallet just a new address that is added to the same wallet.dat file?

Comment: If you click create a new wallet, it creates a new wallet, which will be in a different file.

Comment: Well Allright I hope I can recover them then, thanks for your answers :)

Answer (score 2):

A wallet contains many addresses. An address is not the same thing as a wallet.

When you create a new address with Bitcoin Core, it is stored in the wallet that you are actively using at that time. This means it is stored in the wallet.dat file.